# MySQL query security and timestamp with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm making a quotes and phrases site. I want to post this quotes and prevent `<script>` or similar `<html tags>`, I'm currently using the following query to post and push this data to the database

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `phrases` 
    (`id`, `text`, `date`, `views`, `ip`, `reported`, `strange`, `lang`) 
    VALUES (NULL, '$quote', '$date', '0', '$ip', '0', '0', 'en')
");
```

using the following PHP code

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$quote = $_POST["quote"];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//The query above
?>
```

But I get the following problems:

- ***COMPLETED***: Timestamp is not showing correctly.
- **I'm getting some unescaped characters.**

  For example, I'm trying to post this:

  ```
       <Ω∑©√ß µ„…–å∫∂ƒ™¶§ ~{}œæ€®†¥  øπ[]
  ```

  - If I post this `as is`, it posts

    ```
    <Î©âˆ‘Â©âˆšÃŸ Âµâ€žâ€¦â€“Ã¥âˆ«âˆ‚Æ’ï£¿â„¢Â¶Â§ ~{}Å“Ã¦â‚¬Â®â€ Â¥  Ã¸Ï€[]
    ```
  - If I use `mysql_real_escape_string($quote)`, it posts

    ```
    <Î©âˆ‘Â©âˆšÃŸ Âµâ€žâ€¦â€“Ã¥âˆ«âˆ‚Æ’ï£¿â„¢Â¶Â§ ~{}Å“Ã¦â‚¬Â®â€ Â¥  Ã¸Ï€[]
    ```
  - And if I use `htmlspecialchars(nl2br(stripslashes($quote)))`, it posts

    ```
    &lt;Î©âˆ‘Â©âˆšÃŸ Âµâ€žâ€¦â€“Ã¥âˆ«âˆ‚Æ’ï£¿â„¢Â¶Â§ ~{}Å“Ã¦â‚¬Â®â€ Â¥  Ã¸Ï€[]
    ```
- **I've been warned that this is vulnerable to SQL injection**

How can I prevent this?

As additional information, this is called via AJAX.

Comment: $quote is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @Rook how can I prevent this?

Comment: Don't do that complicated chain of functions to `$quote` when saving it. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` and HTML-escape it only when you output the value.

Comment: `$quote = mysql_real_escape_string($quote);` after doing the first qutoe assign

Comment: To avoid SQL Injection, you need to use prepared statements with PDO (PHP Data Objects). Here is a couple examples: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html

Comment: This may be unrelated about your question but here is a good answers about sql-injection: http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1241723 , maybe you want to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These should do what you want.

On input:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$quote = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["quote"]);
```

On output:

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row["quote"]));
```

Comment: Your issue is not "timestamp" and not "security" anymore... your issue is "encoding" now. The code above is correct, and you should use the `input` code BEFORE entering the data in the database, only. And you should use the `output` code BEFORE displaying the "quote" column content back to the browser. These are the correct places/moments to apply these snippets.

Comment: Now, regarding **encoding**, which is your real issue now: if you want to play nice with these strange characters, my suggestion is that you make **everything UTF-8**. And this "everything" is indeed a lot of things, and you need to take care of them all: 1) Your HTML contents, 2) The encoding of your source code files, 3) The database tables and columns, 4) The database connection - this is the basic. Each one is very important.

Comment: for (1) you should specify UTF-8 at both a `<meta>` tag and a HTTP header (using PHP's `header` function); for (2) you need to check in which character set your source code files are being saved (use your text editor for this) - save them as UTF-8; for (3) you need to check your database tables definitions, and set the character set to UTF-8; finally, for (4) you need to specify UTF-8 as the character set for the communication between PHP and MySQL (the database connection) - the MySQL command is `SET NAMES`

Comment: Read these two articles, specially the second: http://kunststube.net/encoding/  and  http://kunststube.net/frontback/